# Can JSVC execute a script(not java program) if the process is not running?

Tags: java, jsvc

Is that possible for JSVC to check for processId written to file and execute a script(not java program) if the process is not running?

Comment: Why would you use JSVC for that? Wouldn't it be easier to write a bash script?

Comment: The script launches a java program, which id will be written to file. JSVC can monitor the processId and restart it if it fails.